iframe load event not getting captured in React
I am developing a React component in Next.js that uses an iframe for ad rendering. The current implementation directly sets the src attribute of the iframe and attaches a load event listener via useEffect. Upon deployment to production, I observed that the handleIframeLoad method is not getting executed for high number of requests. Below is the relevant code snippet:
...
useEffect(() => {
    const iframe = iframeRef.current;
    ...
    if (iframe) {
       iframe.addEventListener("load", handleIframeLoad);
    }
    ...
    return () => {
       if(iframe) {
           iframe.removeEventListener("load", handleIframeLoad);
       }
    }
}, []);
...
return (
    <iframe
        ref={iframeRef}
        src={props.src}
        style={{
            border: "none"
        }}
    />
);

Since the handleIframeLoad method is not getting executed, it suggests that the "load" event from browser is not getting captured. It seems like the load event is getting triggered before event listener is getting attached to the iframe.
In local testing, I found that adding a check for iframe ready state may work but I am not sure if it covers all cases in production:
if (iframe) {
    if (iframe.contentDocument?.readyState === "complete") {
        handleIframeLoad();
    } else {
        iframe.addEventListener("load", handleIframeLoad);
    }
}

Also adding the onLoad attribute in iframe directly may also work but it will limit the flexibility of removing the event listener dynamically (needed for a specific use case):
return (
    <iframe
        ref={iframeRef}
        src={props.src}
        onLoad={handleIframeLoad}
        style={{
            border: "none"
        }}
    />
);

Basically, I want to know what is the best way to make sure iframe "load" event gets captured every time.

Your readyState example will work for both cases where the iframe is loaded before or after the script runs.
You first example should be fine in production, your problem is in test the iframe loads too quickly.
